# Buffer overflow C++

Tags: c++

intento cambiar las propiedades de visual studio 2019 de manera que me produzca overflow del buffer.

He intentado tocar las opciones pero no lo consigo.

¿Alguien sabe qué propiedades cambiar?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int auth = 0;
char name[10];
char pass[10];

void main()
{
    cout << "Name: ";
    cin >> name;
    cout << "Password: ";
    cin >> pass;

    if (strcmp(pass, "#hello") == 0 && strcmp(name, "admin") == 0) {
        auth = 1;
    }

    if (auth == 0) {
        printf("Access denied");
    }

    else {
        printf("Access granted");
    }
}
```

Comment: No se para que quieres hacer eso, pero no lo vas a hacer en las opciones de visual studio. Si quieres intentar hacer un buffer overflow, lo mas sencillo es que en lugar de leer con `std::cin` leas con `scanf` y escribas mas de 10 caracteres, eso hara la tarea.

Comment: ¿Cómo controlas que ha habido un buffer overflow? El resultado de un buffer overflow es "undefined behavior", lo que significa que el lenguaje no define cómo se debe comportar el programa y el programa es libre de hacer cualquier cosa, con lo cual el resultado depende mucho del compilador y de otras condiciones.

Answer (score 2):

> intento cambiar las propiedades de visual studio 2019 de manera que me produzca overflow del buffer.

Visual Studio no provoca desbordamiento de búferes. El buffer overflow es un concepto, no una opción de configuración.

El desbordamiento de búfer se da cuando se lee o escribe fuera de un búfer; leer fuera del búfer es malo pero escribir fuera del búfer es aún peor: puede comprometer la seguridad de tu código sobre todo si esta escritura está en manos de un tercero malicioso.

---

Doy por sentado que ya sabías todo lo anterior (si lo estoy escribiendo es para futuros lectores) pero tu intención no es provocar desbordamientos de búfer si no comprobar si Visual Studio los detecta. En ese aso tengo malas noticias, ni [c](/questions/tagged/c) ni [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) hacen por defecto comprobaciones de búfer pues hacerlas podrían comprometer el rendimiento del programa; en su lugar delegan en el programador la responsabilidad de controlar los límites del búfer. En el caso de C++ este problema se omite al usar objetos cuyo búfer no está fijo y puede variar dinámicamente mientras que en C se incorporan funciones que permiten hacer comprobaciones de límites como [`printf_s`, `fprintf_s`, `sprintf_s` y `snprintf_s`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) (la "`s`" hace referencia a *secure*).

En todo caso, es posible forzar a Visual Studio a hacer comprobaciones de límite de búfer en modo depuración compilando en C, [este artículo](https://syang.io/2018/12/04/How-to-Product-Buffer-Overflowed.html) (en inglés) explica cómo.